# Antlr is used to parse grammar. What can be used to compose grammar?

Tags: antlr4, business-rules

We have few business rules which are written using string append. We use Antlr lexer and parser to generate tree and evaluate rules.

I am exploring an option where instead of using string append, what can I use to generate business rules which can be used later for parsing by Antlr and for evaluation?

Comment: Since this is all about text processing, any way of generating strings would apply here. How you actually concatenate the input is really a trivial problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike. We follow specific format to concatenate string, but again - it is more of manual approach, where we concatenate all kind parentheses, operator, attributes, I was looking for some kind of tool/framework which can read grammer and help forming string.

Comment: I don't think you'll receive any helpful answers given the fact the problem description is rather vague. Go ahead and reread your question and ask yourself this: "is the problem as I described it now properly explained in these two sentences to someone not familiar with it?"